# Vast data replacement between two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, query-optimization

Assume that we have two tables, named Tb1 and Tb2 and we are going to replace data from one to another. Tb1 is the main source of data and Tb2 is the Destination. This replacement operation has 3 parts.

In the first part we are going to validate all rows in Tb1 and check if they are correct. For example National security code must exactly have 10 digits or a real customer must have a valid birth date so according to these validation rules, 28 different validation methods and error codes have been considered. **During the validation every spoiled row's description and status will be updated to a new state.**

Part 2 fixes the rows' problems and the third one replace them to the Tb2.

For instance this row says that it has 4 different error.

> -- Tb1.desc=6,8,14,16
>   -- Tb1.sts=0

A correct row of data

> -- Tb1.desc=Null  i
>   -- Tb1.sts=1

I have been working on the first part recently and have come up with a solution which works fine but it is too slow. Unfortunately It takes exactly 31 minutes to validate 100,000 rows. In a real situation we are going to validate **more than 2 million records** so it is totally useless despite all it's functionality.

Let's take look at my package :

```
procedure Val_primary IS
      begin    
        Open X_CUSTOMER;
              Loop            
                fetch X_CUSTOMER bulk collect into CUSTOMER_RECORD;
                EXIT WHEN X_CUSTOMER%notfound;                  
                For i in CUSTOMER_RECORD.first..CUSTOMER_RECORD.last loop       
                Val_CTYP(CUSTOMER_RECORD(i).XCUSTYP);
                Val_BRNCH(CUSTOMER_RECORD(i).XBRNCH);

                --Rest of the validations ...

                UptDate_Val(CUSTOMER_RECORD(i).Xrownum);
                end loop;
                CUSTOMER_RECORD.delete;                              
              End loop;
         Close X_CUSTOMER;         
      end Val_primary;
```

Inside a validation procedure :

```
procedure Val_CTYP(customer_type IN number)IS
  Begin
    IF(customer_type<1 or customer_type>3)then
      RW_FINAL_STATUS:=0;
      FINAL_ERR_DSC:=Concat(FINAL_ERR_DSC,ERR_INVALID_CTYP);
    End If;
  End Val_CTYP;
```

Inside the update procedure :

```
procedure UptDate_Val(rownumb IN number) IS 
  begin 
    update tb1 set tb1.xstst=RW_FINAL_STATUS,tb1.xdesc=FINAL_ERR_DSC where xc1customer.xrownum=rownumb; 
    RW_FINAL_STATUS:=1;
    FINAL_ERR_DSC:=null;
  end UptDate_Val;
```

**Is there any way to reduce execution time ?** 
It must be done less than 20 minutes for more than 2 million records.

Comment: Read up on the MERGE statement.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Should i change my update statement to merge statement ? Are you going to tell me to merge a table with itself ?

Comment: MERGE is probably a better option than UPDATE, but that refers only to the THIRD part of your three-part process. I believe your entire question here is about the FIRST part, right? (MERGE will be used to update values in Tb2 with values from Tb1, where do you see "merge a table with itself"?)

Comment: Why is it useless? Isn't this a one-time operation? Or something that happens very rarely, so you can trigger the integration during weekends or over night? 2 million would take a little more than 10 hours... if the data is consistent afterwards it's worth it, no?

Comment: Your outer loop doesn't look right. The `bulk collect` has no `limit` so it's fetching all the rows into memory in one go - it's not really a loop. (If it was, the `exit` would be in the wrong place.) Naming an array 'customer_record' is pretty confusing as well (how is it a record?) And is your standard to prefix all cursors with `x_`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe each validation check could be a `case` expression within an inline view, and you could concatenate them etc in the enclosing query, giving you a single SQL statement that could drive an `update`. Something along the lines of:

```
select xxx, yyy, zzz  -- whatever columns you need from xc1customer
     , errors  -- concatenation of all error codes that apply
     , case when errors is not null then 0 else 1 end as status
from   ( select xxx, yyy, zzz
              , trim(ltrim(val_ctyp||' ') || ltrim(val_abc||' ') || ltrim(val_xyz||' ') || etc...) as errors
         from   ( select c.xxx, c.yyy, c.zzz
                       , case when customer_type < 1 or customer_type > 3 then err_invalid_ctyp end as val_ctyp
                       , case ... end as val_abc
                       , case ... end as val_xyz
                  from   xc1customer c
                )
       );
```

Sticking with the procedural approach, the slow part seems to be the single-row update. There is no advantage to bulk-collecting all 20 million rows into session memory only to apply 20 million individual updates. The quick fix would be to add a `limit` clause to the `bulk collect` (and move the `exit` to the bottom of the loop where it should be), have your validation procedures set a value in the array instead of updating the table, and batch the updates into one `forall` per loop iteration.

You can be a bit freer with passing records and arrays in and out of procedures rather than having everything a global variable, as passing by reference means there is no performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential lines of attack.

1. **Specific implementation.** Collections are read into session memory. This is usually quite small compared to global memory allocation. Reading 100000 longish rows into session memory is a bad idea and can cause performance issues. So breaking up the process into smaller chunks (say 1000 rows) will most likely improve throughput.
2. **General implementation.** What is the point of the tripartite process? Updating Table1 with some error flags is an expensive activity. A more efficient approach would be to apply the fixes to the data in the collection and apply that to Table2. You can write a log record if you need to track what changes are made.

Applying these suggestion you'd end up with a single procedure which looks a bit like this:

```
procedure one_and_only is
begin    
    open x_customer;
    << tab_loop >>
    loop            
        fetch x_customer bulk collect into customer_record
            limit 1000;
        exit when customer_record.count() = 0;  
        << rec_loop >>
        for i in customer_record.first..customer_record.last loop       
            val_and_fix_ctyp(customer_record(i).xcustyp);
            val_and_fix_brnch(customer_record(i).xbrnch);

            --rest of the validations ...

        end loop rec_loop;

        -- apply the cleaned data to target table
        forall j in 1..customer_record.count()
            insert into table_2
            values customer_record(j);                              
     end loop tab_loop;
    close x_customer;         
end one_and_only;
```

Note that this approach requires the `customer_record` collection to match the projection of the target table. Also, don't use `%notfound` to test for end of the cursor unless you can guarantee the total number of read records is *an exact multiple of the LIMIT number*.